# WSO2 Emm Agent update.apk open failed EACCES

Tags: android, wso2-iot

We are testing the emm agent in android kitkat 4.4.2, we defined a policy to force the installation of an application that we published into the store.

When the device try to download the apk from the server we face the following error :

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Download/update.apk: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied

Thanks!

Gabriel.

Answer (score 0):

Does this error come from an actual device, or from the Android Simulator? If its from the simulator, it could be you haven't set an sd-card size. Open the Android Virtual Device (AVD) manager from Eclipse and edit the AVD you are using. Set an SD-Card size large enough to hold your application.

Comment: Hi, the error comes from the actual device. It works well on the simulator.